# Mysql shell windows: existing database unknown

Tags: mysql

I've been getting insane for all day trying to make it work but there's no way for me.
I've installed mysql under windows 8.
I've createf a database called Books and I've granted all privileges on this database to me. I've checked that everything is good by tiping "show privileges"...All is fine. If i perform "show databases" I see "books" in the list.
Anyway when I try "\u Books" or \u books", I get an error saying "database books unknown".
Instead, if I try to access the database through a gui (xampp) then all works. I can access the database, I see the tables and I can perform queries. Anyway for my habits I prefere using the prompt/shell...
How can I do?

Comment: Your `mysql` (console) is probably not connecting to the same server your "gui" is connecting, check that

Comment: Please, may you tell me how to check it? Because I'm newbie to mysql...it's strange, because I see books database in the list...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't add a semicolon after the \u command - the MySQL client doesn't like this. I prefer the "use" command, it's more forgiving if you add a semicolon by mistake.

```
mysql> \u test;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test;'
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> \u test
Database changed
mysql> use test
Database changed
```